# Why AlertDialog doesn't work from Activty RecycleView Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I don't know why the below code wasn't work for Activity RecycleView Adapter class but I did it with Fragment RecycleView Adapter class and absoulty work. Can anyone help?

```
        viewHolder.rlCV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            final View vv = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_pdf, null);
            final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    mContext);

            alert.setView(vv);
            dialog = alert.create();
            dialog.show();

            ImageButton btnCancel=vv.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel12);
            pdfView=vv.findViewById(R.id.pdfView);

           //new RetrivePdfStremQbank().execute(cvUri);

            btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Error Message Show on Run:

> android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window --
> token null is not valid; is your activity running?
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:1003)
> at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:384)
> at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:101)
> at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:430)
> at com.rpaskewdevelopment.suap.Adapter.Comment_info_Adapter$2.onClick(Comment_info_Adapter.java:127)

Comment: `mContext` is not an `Activity`, which possibly means that the `Adapter` was given the wrong `Context` in its constructor call.

Comment: private Context mContext;                                                                                                       yes. I defined the Context is  mContext on Adapter

Comment: In the `Activity`, when you instantiated the `Adapter`, you passed the wrong `Context`. For example, you probably have something like `MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext());`. That's the wrong `Context`. You need to pass the current `Activity` instead; e.g., `new MyAdapter(this)`, or `new MyAdapter(MyActivity.this)`, as necessary.

Comment: Pass one arrayList and A string with the adapter. Please check the code:                comment_info_adapter =new Comment_info_Adapter(getApplicationContext(), commentModels,file);

                recyclerView.setAdapter(comment_info_adapter);

Comment: It's the first argument in the constructor call: `new Comment_info_Adapter(this, commentModels, file)`

Comment: Oh. Man. I Mess up. I understood know, what are you try to emend. It's okay now. Thank you very much and appreciated :).

Answer (score 0):

You should pass Activity context to your adapter and then use it to create Alert dialog.